# Deleting Contributions

Tags: contributions, contribution-page, data-import, delete

I imported 50 new contributions but it did not import correctly.

**How do I delete a contribution?**

Previous suggestions have been to follow this process:

Contributions > Find Contributions > *Enter criteria and Select "Search" > *Check Desired Contribution(s) > Select "delete"

**But a "Delete" button does not exist. Is there another  way?**

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There should be a 'Delete contribution' option in the list of actions:

[image]

If you don't see it there, check that you have the 'Delete contributions' permission.

Comment: It was an issues with permissions. It is fixed now. Thank you!